# Howto archive a new response page for a view block with exposed filters?

Tags: views, ajax, redirection

In drupal 7 i have created a view with a page and a block.

Inside the views block I have exposed filters. I placed this views block on the frontpage. The exposed filters only work with ajax enabled, otherwise the exposed filters are not visible.

If you use the exposed filters on the front page, ajax will show the results on the front page.

I like to archive to redirect the results to the views page. Where do I need to change the code to tell ajax to use a specific page?

In other words, there are many results, if you use the exposed filters on the frontpage. Thats why I need a redirection to style the results.